# Bigquery using wildcard for project Id

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, wildcard

Is there any way to use wildcards for bigquery project Id?

I have several bigquery projects as below(all start with **sales-** and end with **-eu**):

```
`sales-appliances-564-eu`
`sales-electrics-564-eu`
`sales-gadgets-564-eu`
...
```

They all have a dataset called sales and a table called **sales-growth**.
I am wondering how I can query all the sale-growth tables using wildcards not union because there are many of projects?

For examples:

```
SELECT * from `sales-appliances-564-eu.sales.sales-growth`
UNION ALL
SELECT * from `sales-electrics-564-eu.sales.sales-growth`
UNION ALL
...
```

I tried below query and it gives an error:

```
SELECT * from `sales-*-eu.sales.sales-growth`
```

Error:
**Invalid project ID 'sales-*-eu'. Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. Some project IDs also include domain name separated by a colon. IDs must start with a letter and may not end with a dash.**

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [`wildcard`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) to query across all the projects.Wildcard is useful when a dataset contains multiple, similarly named tables that have compatible schemas.

Either you need to use `union all` and mention all the tables individually or you may try to achieve the same result using `Dynamic SQL`.

Below is an example using `arrays`.

```
declare queries array<string> default [];
declare projects array<string>;
set projects = ['project-id-1','project-id-2']; --mention all project ids here

/*
Once you have set the project values you need to create `select` statements 
dynamically for all the projects.
*/
for val IN (select * from unnest(projects) project) do
   set queries =  queries || [format('select * from `%s.sales.sales_growth`', val.project)];
end for;

--You can run the below statement to verify values of the `queries` array
 --select  queries

--aggregating all the queries and executing it
execute immediate (select string_agg(query, ' union all ') from unnest(queries) query);
```

Output:
[image]